# Toggle between production and development

Tags: python, dev-to-production

I have a global flag in one of my modules, `config/top.py`:

```
RUNNING_MODE = "production"  # could also be "development", set manually
```

Depending on this flag, I would like to include some production/development settings. For example, in `production.py` I want to have:

```
LOG_LEVEL = "WARNING"
```

And in `development.py`:

```
LOG_LEVEL = "INFO"
```

(there are much more settings to be set)

The goal is to be able to use those settings transparently in any of my modules, let's say `test.py`:

```
from config.settings import LOG_LEVEL
```

This would use the right setting, either from `production.py` or from `development.py`, depending on `RUNNING_MODE`.

Is there any accepted approach to handle this kind of setup? How would I structure the directories/modules so that, just by changing the `RUNNING_MODE` in `config/top.py` the whole configuration happens transparently?

Note: I prefer not to have this in the build process, but to have it embedded in the module structure. That is, I do not want the build process to modify any of my modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this.

Following is the folder structure:

```
> config/
    settings.py
    production.py
    development.py
```

Now in settings.py:

```
RUNNING_MODE = "production"  # could also be "development", set manually

if ENVIRONMENT == "production":
    from production import *
elif ENVIRONMENT == "development":
    from development import *
```

Keep all your environment dependent settings in individual files.

And then, in views.py or any other file in project.

```
from config.settings import LOG_LEVEL
```